# HTML CSS make divs side by side, out of screen width

Tags: html, css

My goal is to put div with width=100vw, after that div there should be second div with width for example 300px (so that second div should be out of screen). I tried many things with float, display inline and so on, now I don't have any more ideas.

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Here is fiddle with example code

https://jsfiddle.net/kg5ea4sc/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `white-space: nowrap` on parent element and `display: inline-block` on two inner elements. Also maybe you want to add `vertical-align: top` so it will look like this [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/kg5ea4sc/14/)

```css
.element {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#div1{
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width:100vw;
  height: 80px;
}

#div2{
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width:300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/kg5ea4sc/18/

The second div is outside of the screen. You'll have to manipulate either it's position or the `overflow:hidden` property on the container if you want to see it though.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#div1{
  background: green;
  width:100vw;
  height: 80px;
}

#div2{
  background: red;
  width:300px;
  height: 100px;
}

div{
    display:inline-block;
}

#container{
    width:100vw;
   white-space:nowrap;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nyzvbvo7/1/

You can scoll to the right to see the second `div`

What I changed:

I added

```
body {
  width: calc(100vw + 300px);
  margin: 0;
}
#div1, #div2 {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
}
```

So I made the body wide enough to hold both containers and set the container's `display` to  `inline-block`. `vertical-align: top;` can be left out, the the containers will be algned at their baseline (which can vary depending on the content)